# Close a window when mouse got released

Tags: java, swing

I've been trying to solve this problem for quite long and I haven't been able to find a solution myself, neither on google.

First of all, this is what I have on my graphic user interface:
[gui image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFJ65.png)

What I want to do is: When I press my mouse in one of logotipos, I want to open a window while I'm pressing the mouse. When I stop pressing it, the window closes.

This is what I have on my code:

```
lblAwayTeamPic.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    TeamRosterDialog teamWindow = null;
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        teamWindow = new TeamRosterDialog(SelectTeamsUI.this, "Cleveland Cavaliers", "2017/2018");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
        if(teamWindow != null)
            teamWindow.dispose();
    }
});
```

He's detecting each mouse event, because I already tried to print "Pressed" & "Released" in each method. However, when I implement with Dialog he open it up, but dispose() doesn't work :\

I thought doing `teamWindow.setVisible(false)`, however I don't consider it as a viable way, since it will consume memory anyways if I'm not mistaken.

I can give you more code if you need, but the main problem is here, I think so. If you need context, this MouseListener is inside of a Combo Box ActionListener (To change the name when you choose it).

Comment: Is TeamRosterDialog a subclass of JDialog? Making it a JFrame instead might be a step in the right direction.

Comment: It's also possible that `mouseReleased` won't be called if some other component obtains focus

Comment: Solved it! I had to `extends JFrame` instead of `extends JDialog` as @StefanReich said.

Thanks both of you for helping me :)

Comment: I wasn't sure about that either @MadProgrammer. Apparently it does as the problem is solved now :) Glad to help